# R Shiny: Print output from dynamically created bucket lists

Tags: r, shiny

I am unable to print the entire output of bucket list inputs (`verbatimTextOutput("bucket_outputs")`). See:

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

example_Table = cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c("a","b","c","d"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("Dyanmic_Bucket"),
  uiOutput("Dyanmic_Bucket_2"),
  
  ###The following output is incomplete
  verbatimTextOutput("bucket_outputs")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rank_list_items <- lapply(seq(nrow(example_Table)), function(x) {
    add_rank_list(
      text = example_Table[x,1],
      labels =  example_Table[x,2]
    )
  })
  
  output$Dyanmic_Bucket <- renderUI({
    do.call("bucket_list", args = c(
      list(header = "",
           group_name = "Dyanmic_Bucket",
           orientation = "horizontal"),
      rank_list_items
    ))
  })
  
  
  rank_list_items_2 <- lapply(seq(nrow(example_Table)), function(x) {
    add_rank_list(
      text = example_Table[x,1],
      labels =  example_Table[x,2]
    )
  })
  
  output$Dyanmic_Bucket_2 <- renderUI({
    do.call("bucket_list", args = c(
      list(header = "",
           group_name = "Dyanmic_Bucket",
           orientation = "horizontal"),
      rank_list_items_2
    ))
  })
  
 
  output$bucket_outputs = renderPrint(input$Dyanmic_Bucket)
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Initially, it only prints the output of `Dyanmic_Bucket_2`, but even this is inconsistent upon re-ordering, or doubling up some of the options.

Renaming the group name of each bucket will not work, as I would then no longer be able to drag and drop across the different rows.

I would like to see a printed output of both dynamically created buckets. Help much appreciated.

Comment: did you define "add_rank_list()" somewhere else? or is it from a library?

Comment: It's defined within the ```sortable``` package.